# Different graph results when using ggplot vs when using base R functions?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, data-analysis, graphing

I am creating some simple graphs for a project in R. I got unexpected results when using the ggplot2 package, and so I defaulted back to base R. When recreating the plot in base R, I got the correct result. Now I am just wondering why different results were produced?

Initially, this was the code and result using ggplot (which is incorrect):

```r
ggplot(KBUF, aes(x = TEMP, y = HGHT)) +
geom_line(aes(color = "Temperature"), size = 1) +
geom_line(aes(x = DEWP, color = "Dew Point"), size = 1) +
scale_color_manual(values = c("blue", "red")) +
labs(x = "Temperature (°C)", y = "Height")
```

[image: This is the output plot]

The correct plot I made in base R

[image]

has the following code:

```r
plot(KNKX$TEMP, KNKX$HGHT, type = "l", col = "blue", xlab = "Temperature (°C)", ylab = "Height")

lines(KNKX$DEWP, KNKX$HGHT, col = "red")

legend("topright", legend = c("Temperature", "Dew Point"), col = c("blue", "red"), lty = 1)
```

Why are they different?

Comment: `geom_line` takes all the (x, y) co-ordinates and orders them from smallest x value to largest x value, then draws a line through these points. If you want to draw a line that goes through the points _in the order they appear_ you need to use `geom_path`, not `geom_line`

Comment: @BenBolker the lack of MRE put me off posting as an answer, and I assumed it was probably a dupe I couldn't find. I suppose a simple circle does as a demo.

Comment: I appreciate that. I often want to answer in comments for the same reasons. I try to hold back (I don't always succeed). (It is especially frustrating when it's harder to find the duplicate than to write up a new answer, although are worse things than writing a good answer and then having someone else find the dupe.)

Comment: I also think you're not required to go to the trouble of writing up an MRE if the OP hasn't, if you're reasonably certain that you can answer the question without having a test case (which in this case is true).

Answer (score 5):

`geom_line` takes all the (x, y) co-ordinates and orders them from smallest x value to largest x value, then draws a line through these points. If you want to draw a line that goes through the points in the order they appear you need to use `geom_path`, not `geom_line`

For example, suppose I have a data frame that has the co-ordinates of a circle ordered counter-clockwise:

```r
df <- data.frame(x = sin(pi * seq(-1, 1, 0.01)),
                 y = cos(pi * seq(-1, 1, 0.01)))
```

If I plot this with `geom_line`, I get a mess, because the line joins all the points according to their x value:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) + geom_line()
```

[image]

If I want to preserve ordering, I simply use `geom_path` instead of `geom_line`:

```r
ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) + geom_path()
```

[image]